# PushWoosh - Customizing push notifications

Tags: android, pushwoosh

I'm checking the example in PushWoosh's FAQ section: [Customizing Push Notification](http://docs.pushwoosh.com/docs/android-faq#customizing-push-notifications)

It states that

> The last step is to set your notification Factory to the Push Manager:
>
> `pushManager.setNotificationFactory(new ActionNotificationFactory());`

But it doesn't mention where this should be set.. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can just set this at the very start of your app. This will make sure that all the push notifications will be handled by your push notifications Factory.

Please make sure your Factory uses default constructor only (without any extra parameters), as this way it will be created when the push notifications comes in the background.